# Why isn't strtok separating this string correctly? C

Tags: c

- The string inside riga_corrente is: `"apelle figlio di apollo"`.
- The content of d[0].stringa is "pelle", compresso_s is "$11$".
- Temp is an array of 200 char.

I want to have `"a$11$ figlio di apollo"` inside `riga_corrente` but I only get `"a$11$ fig"` and I don't understand why.

Part of my code:

```
strcpy(temp,strtok(riga_corrente,d[i].stringa));
strcat(temp,compresso_s);
strcat(temp,strtok(NULL,d[i].stringa));
strcpy(riga_corrente,temp);
```

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  If you had provided an MCVE, your first paragraph would be unnecessary because your code would show the initializations.  You'd probably avoid the array `d` and the structure type; those seem to be unnecessary (you'd provide the data, but not the structure or the array).  How big is `riga_corrente`?  How were we supposed to know?  Note that the delimiter to `strtok()` is any one of the characters listed, so the `l` in `figlio` is a delimiter too.  This probably explains your output.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad example, btw riga_corrente is 200. I didn't know that the delimiter could be any character. Is there a way to put only the entire word 'pelle' as a delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your question converted into an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char riga_corrente[200] = "apelle figlio di apollo";
    char stringa[] = "pelle";
    char compresso_s[] = "$11$";
    char temp[200];

    strcpy(temp, strtok(riga_corrente, stringa));
    strcat(temp, compresso_s);
    strcat(temp, strtok(NULL, stringa));
    strcpy(riga_corrente, temp);
    printf("[%s]\n", riga_corrente);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output, which means the library functions are working as designed (but apparently not as you expected):

```
[a$11$ fig]
```

The first call to `strtok()` stops at the `p` in `apelle`, zapping it with a null byte, and returning a pointer to the `a`, which is copied into `temp`.  You then append the `$11$` from `compresso_s`.  The next call to `strtok()` skips over the `e`, `l`, `l` and `e` of `apelle` and starts the token at the blank.  The letters `f`, `i`, `g` don't match the delimiters, but `l` does, so the `l` in `figlio` is zapped with a null byte and a pointer to the blank is returned.  This string is correctly added to the end of `temp`, and then `temp` overwrites `riga_corrente` because of the `strcpy()`.

At first glance, you could fix it by changing the delimiter in the second call to `strtok()`, maybe to just a newline, or even an empty string.  However, that leaves the `elle` of `apelle` as part of the output too.  Fixing that requires different technology — possibly using the underrated (and little known) [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html) and [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) functions that have been in Standard C since the 1989 edition, or possibly using [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) to find the string `pelle`.

It's not very elegant (there's probably a function in here trying to escape), but this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char riga_corrente[200] = "apelle figlio di apollo";
    char stringa[] = "pelle";
    char compresso_s[] = "$11$";
    char temp[200];

    char *source = riga_corrente;
    char *p1 = strstr(source, stringa);
    if (p1 == NULL)
        strcpy(temp, source);
    else
    {
        *p1 = '\0';
        strcpy(temp, source);
        source = p1 + strlen(stringa);
    }
    strcat(temp, compresso_s);
    if (p1 != NULL)
    {
        p1 = strstr(source, stringa);
        if (p1 == NULL)
            strcat(temp, source);
        else
        {
            *p1 = '\0';
            strcat(temp, source);
        }
    }
    strcpy(riga_corrente, temp);
    printf("[%s]\n", riga_corrente);

    return 0;
}
```

There's no buffer overflow protection etc here; it usually won't be needed, but in principle, if `pelle` never appeared in `riga_corrente`, you could get a buffer overflow.